# Cesiumjs calculating pitch, yaw, heading from vector

Tags: javascript, rotation, linear-algebra, quaternions, cesiumjs

I have one of Cesium's models loaded into the scene, and I have two points which I want to use in order to calculate the orientation of the model and this is the function I created.

```
// calculate the direction which the model is facing
calculateOrientation({ position, nextPosition }) {

    let dir = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
    let normalizedDir = new Cesium.Cartesian3();

    Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(nextPosition, position, dir);
    Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(dir, normalizedDir);

    var heading = Math.acos(normalizedDir.x);
    var pitch = Math.acos(normalizedDir.y);
    var roll = 0;

    var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll);
    var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr);
    return orientation;
}
```

But the rotations I get don't make any sense. Is my math wrong?

### UPDATE

After the first answer by @Keshet, I looked up how to find an angle between a plane and a vector. I figured if I find the angle between the normal of each plane and -90, I should get the correct angle, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Also I don't know how Cesium Axis work, and I cant find any document describing it. For example the XY plane and etc.

```
    let dir = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
    let xyNormal = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0,0,1);
    let xzNormal = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0,1,0);
    let yzNormal = new Cesium.Cartesian3(1,0,0);

    Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(nextPosition, position, dir);

    let xyAngle = Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO - Cesium.Cartesian3.angleBetween(dir, xyNormal);
    let xzAngle = Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO - Cesium.Cartesian3.angleBetween(dir, xzNormal);
    let yzAngle = Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO - Cesium.Cartesian3.angleBetween(dir, yzNormal);
```

### UPDATE 2

Following @IIan suggestion using atan2, here is the code:

```
    Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(position, nextPosition, dir);

    // create the mapped to plane vectors, and get the 
    // normalized versions
    let xyMappedVectorNormalized = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 0);
    let xyMappedVector = new Cesium.Cartesian3(dir.x, dir.y, 0);

    let xzMappedVectorNormalized = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 0);
    let xzMappedVector = new Cesium.Cartesian3(dir.x, 0, dir.z);

    let yzMappedVectorNormalized = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 0);
    let yzMappedVector = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, dir.y, dir.z);

    Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(xyMappedVector, xyMappedVectorNormalized);
    Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(xzMappedVector, xzMappedVectorNormalized);
    Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(yzMappedVector, yzMappedVectorNormalized);

    // calculate the angles
    let xyAngle = Math.atan2(xyMappedVectorNormalized.y, xyMappedVectorNormalized.x);
    let xzAngle = Math.atan2(xzMappedVectorNormalized.z, xzMappedVectorNormalized.x);
    let yzAngle = Math.atan2(yzMappedVectorNormalized.z, yzMappedVectorNormalized.y);
```

Comment: A negative vote doesnt give feedback to how this question can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to explain what the heading, pitch, and roll angles represent.

1. The heading angle represents the angle in radians with respect to the XY - plane
2. The pitch angle represents the angle in radians with respect to the XZ - plane
3. The roll angle respresents the angle in radians with respect to the YZ plane

You cannot simply use the x / y to compute the heading / pitch

```
var heading = Math.acos(normalizedDir.x);
var pitch = Math.acos(normalizedDir.y);
```

You need to get the total angle on each of these planes.

On the XY plane, you will use the normalized |(X, Y)|
on the XZ plane, you will use the normalized |(X, Z)|
on the YZ plane you will use the normalized |(Y, Z)|

---

**Update**

|(X, Y)|  represents a point on the Unit circle.

where (sin(theta), cos(theta)) = |(X, Y)|

IE when theta = 0,   |(X, Y)| = (1, 0)
when theta = PI/2, |(X, Y)| = (0, 1)

this theta would be then the angle you use for the heading

---

then subsequently, you can call the arctan2 function to calculate the angle with respect to the plane.

atan2(y, x) = theta  where [x, y] are calculated from above using the corresponding normalized 2D vector

To note: atan2 gives angles bounded from (-PI, PI]

**Example**

If your 3D vector is (1, 2, 3) -- on the XY plane X = 1, Y = 2.

Then if you normalize (1, 2) => (1 / sqrt(5), 2 / sqrt(5))

Then you can use atan2(2 / sqrt(5), 1 / sqrt(5) to calculate the angle in radians for the heading

Comment: @IIanKeshet what magnitude is |(X, Y)| representing? my linear algebra is rusty what is (X,Y)?

Comment: I have given an example in the question. Look at the answer again

Comment: Also, I defined what X, Y are representing

Comment: so basically `atan2(normalizedDir.x, normalizedDir.y)` ?

Comment: yes, but not the normalized 3D vector, the normalized 2D vector. And it is the other way around. atan2(y, x)   -- that's just how the function works

Comment: You have to be a bit careful though, because normalized of (0, 0) -- is undefined and won't work.

Comment: I added code reflecting what you said but it doesn't work

Comment: Might be a good idea to show a picture why it is wrong. -- Could be that your up vector is actually Y and not Z. 
I'd recommend showing a picture of what it does. 

To test if the resulting quaternion is the correct one:   Multiply Q * (1, 0, 0)  -- this result should be |(nextPosition - position)|